Generating a figure with the package TikZ
I am working on an article in LaTeX and am trying to generate a figure with the help of the package TikZ. Since it's my fist time using this package (and I've only just started learning to use LaTeX) I would greatly appreciate some step-by-step instructions with an explanation. 

Welcome to TeX.SX! On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Look for the document called "A very minimal introduction to TikZ". It will give you a basic idea of how tikz works and answer a lot of your questions. You can then come back to us with an MWE we can help you tweak.

I suggest you use the forest package.

If you are just starting to learn TikZ, start with the tutorial at the start of the user guide https://texdoc.org/serve/pgfmanual.pdf/0 This should give you enough basics to draw some simple shapes, like a rectangle with text in it. Once you managed the basics, show what you tried and I'm sure people here can help you with the rest.

I like forest, but it has a steeper learning curve than TikZ and I wouldn't necessarily recommend starting with it without knowing any TikZ at all.

Welcome to TeX.SX, If I may, I suggest this answer of mine. It has a diagram that can be used as base for your question.

Note that I think I ought not answer do-it-for-me questions.
Here's a very quick skeleton using forest which you can substitute your labels into to get a sense of how it works.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={draw,rounded corners,grow'=0,parent anchor=children,child anchor=parent}
  [root
  [a[aa[aaa]][ab[aba][abb]]]
  [b[ba[baa]][bb[bba][bbb]]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


The forest manual is thorough but rather like being thrown into the deep end. In the Arctic.
I wrote a simple introduction to forest in this answer. There is also a 'quickstart' guide to the package. The first of these happens to be focused on linguistics. The second is designed for linguists.
[Note to other readers: if you are interested in using forest for logic, there are better places to start aimed specifically at using forest for tableaux: manual for prooftrees and introduction with 'quickstart' style guide. Note that I wrote prooftrees, but I did not bribe Peter Smith for his write-up!]

Thank you, I'll try working with that.

@JamesCatch I added some pointers which may be helpful. The last bit probably won't be, but I included it in case people trying to draw tableaux read this. But the other pointers are fairly focused on linguistics, so likely to be useful.
